# How to replace variable value in js file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a java script file called require.config.js

There is a variable in it called "waitSeconds" with a value of 15 and I want to replace the 15 with a 60 - using powershell.   I know I could use replace to replace 15 with 60 - but I don't know that the value will always be 15.  So I want to replace the value for "waitSeconds"

Here's an example of the file - want to change whatever the value for "waitSeconds" is (in this case 15) - to a different value -ie 60

```
require.config({

  "waitSeconds": 15,

  "unitTestUser": {

    "Username": "user",

    "Password": "password"

  },

  "paths": {

    "modules": "modules",

    "semantic-ui": "client/ui/semantic-ui/semantic",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Get-Content` to read the file and `-replace` to replace that particular line and set the new value, for example:

```
$content = Get-Content path/to/require.config.js -Raw
$content -replace '("waitSeconds":\s*)\d+,', '${1}60,' | Set-Content path/to/require.config.js
```

Comment: Thanks so much Santiago.  That solved my issue :)